# Why BDD test scenarios are separated?

Tags: tdd, bdd, lettuce

When I'm writing tests using lettuce, I want to create a huge scenario that contains an user making every possible action on website. But testing tools are making me aim separating them. What is the benefit of it?

Answer (score 2):

You put "BDD" into the title of this question, and tag it with both "BDD" and "TDD" tags.  So you're interested in *Behavior* **Driven Development** and *Test* **Driven Development**.

Why should you drive development a little bit at a time instead of driving the entire application all at once?  That's what your question amounts to in the context of BDD and TDD.

You are going to write one method, one additional bit of functionality, next.  Of course that bit will contribute to the overall behavior, and it's good to have an understanding of the overall behavior you're trying to develop, but you need focus.  You need to know when that next bit is working and complete, so you can move on to the next bit.  A full-blown test of the entire app will fail at the beginning; it will fail after your first bit of functionality is implemented; it will fail when you are half-done, and it will fail when you are 99% done.  Unfortunately, it will probably also fail when you are 100% done - and now you'll have to find where you went wrong, and fix that bit (or those bits).

But if you write a test of just that new bit of functionality, it will fail right now, and it will pass in five minutes or ten minutes or twenty minutes or maybe an hour.  Then you'll know it's time for the next bit.  And it will keep passing as you write more tests and implement more functionality.  When you're 99% done, you'll have 99% of your ultimate tests passing - and 100%, minus one, of your current tests.  You can see your real progress and know that what you have written up to date is really working.

That's why you should write small tests, one at a time, and make them pass one at a time.

Comment: Carl has explained well why you should go for small tests during development. This does not only apply to bdd tests but to unit tests (and I often like to drive my unit tests with gherkin).

Another important criterion is your use of BDD tests as a regression pack. Having one long scenario may hide some serious problems. Imagine that you have a chain of features tested in one test: A, B, C, D. If your test starts failing at B then you know nothing about the state of your C and D features until you 'fix' your D node.

Answer (score 1):

Three important things come to my mind:

- readability: when a scenario fails, it is easier to understand from a first glance at the scenario's name what went wrong and significantly easier to fix when it's small and focused
- maintainability: it is easier to modify/update small scenario
- independence: large scenarios tend to make steps dependent on each other. This way, the further an action in a scenario is, the more it is depending on previous actions in more complicated ways that are hard to comprehend. This directly influences two previous reasons.